# The descrTable function reported an error

Tags: r

When the descrTable function is used, one of the five categorical variables always fails to output statistical results, while the other categorical variables, such as the three categorical variables, can output results normally. The output will only work if the five categorical variables are changed to numeric, which is not what I want. Code error results are:
Error in compareGroups.fit(X = X, y = y, include.label = include.label, :
None variable can be computed

The descrTable function is expected to output quantity and percentage statistics for each level 0,1,2,3,4 of the five categorical variables, rather than continuous results

Comment: Can you share reproducible code?

Comment: result3<-descrTable(y~ ., data = data,method = NA)

Comment: Should I change some parameter values？

Comment: This set of data contains several categorical variables, but all the other variables can produce normal results, except for one variable. All data were examined without missing values

Comment: @我没有question please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to know how to make a reproducible example. The package [`reprex`](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/) is also helpful for this